# What is a Smooth Word™?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, word-property

If a word follows a single property, I call it a Smooth Word™. There isn't much of maths and/or encoding and stuff; it requires a bit of out-of-the-box thinking. Resemblance between words of each pair is intentional (so that you can compare similar words), but of no relevance to the actual answer.

```
SMOOTH WORDS™   NOT SMOOTH WORDS™
pentagon        police
infant          infantry
encryption      encrypt
technical       technique
ten             twenty
I               thy
water           slaughter
aces            ace
west            east
privately       publicly
```

Comment: The word request thing won't work and wouldn't happen anyway

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Why?

Comment: First off most words suggested won't have the word property and if we were to submit words that do follow the rule we'd have to know the rule first, secondly 10 users for each word is way to high and thirdly it's just not really a great idea

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The words are a very common, it is easy to stumble upon them by chance. Ok no, I didn't mean 10 users for one word. I meant 10 users, each submitting their own pair of words.

Comment: If you feel like it is necessary, add 5 random words to each column. Also, if publically/publicly are two words, remove one of those. It just confuses people, and pedantic users will ask what purpose the forward slash serves, etc. Post a clean puzzle.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, if the words are rather easy to stumble across, i.e. Very common words then that means this questions isn't great because the words are supposed to be hard to get. Don't want to put you down just want to give advice for future puzzles

Comment: thorn vs. thorny and wheeljack vs wheeljoe (the last two are intentionally meaningless)

Comment: Okay I've removed it then.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh I didn't know that at all. What's wrong with the words being common? Like I guess every second or third word is a smooth word....does that mean I should remove this puzzle?

Comment: For what it's worth, I completely disagree with @beastlygerbil that the words being common is a problem. As long as the rule is deterministic, challenging to find and somewhat interesting, it doesn't matter if there's ten or ten thousand words in the set.

Comment: Shouldn't technical and technique be other way round. Please confirm

Comment: @Tejasva It's fine. I noticed another major error, though, the headings were wrong.

Comment: I'm with Alconja: it's not necessarily a bad thing if (say) about half of all words fall into one category and about half into the other. (Though that may make it harder to spot what the ones in one category have in common.)

Comment: Hahaha @ghosts_in_the_code That completely changed my logic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> A word is SMOOTH if and only if the number of vowels it has is the same as the number of syllables. 
>  For the purposes of this solution, the vowels are *a, e, i, o, u* (I'm not counting *y* as a vowel)

Examples

> **encryption** has three vowels (**e, i, o**) and three syllables. 
>  **encrypt** has one vowel (**e**) and two syllables.
>  **technical** has three vowels and three syllables. 
>  **technique** has four vowels and two syllables.

Comment: I think Y is considered a vowel in those words.

Comment: @fdr I should be more specific. For the purpose of this solution, I do not count 'y' as a vowel. I'll add an extra line for clarification.

Comment: Cheers, correct answer.